# How share resx files to another projects in same solution in Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, resources

I have used the Asp.Net Core MVC where I have the localization using `resx` files.

The configuration is following:

```
services.AddMvc()
                .AddViewLocalization(
                    LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
                    opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
                opts =>
                {
                    var supportedCultures = new[]
                    {
                        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                        new CultureInfo("en")
                    };

                    opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
                    // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
                    opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                    // UI strings that we have localized.
                    opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                });
```

I have two projects in solution:

```
- Application.Web
- Application.Tests
```

I have tried to create some integration test for example try access the home page and assert if there exist some text like this:

```
[Fact]
    public async Task ReturnInitialHomePage()
    {
        //Get claims for admin
        _client.SetAdminClaimsViaHeaders();

        // Act
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/home/index");

        // Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // How here load the resx file with title?
        responseString.Contains("Home Page Title").Should().BeTrue();
    }
```

My issue is - How can I share my resx file into the project Application.Tests:

```
Application.Web\Resources\Views\Home\Index.en.resx

responseString.Contains("Home Page Title").Should().BeTrue(); - How can I read the key from resx file?
```

I have tried use - Application.Web.Resources.View.Home.Index but these path doesn't exist.

Try used access modifier to public - but unfortunately still cannot find.
[image]

Another issue is - is it possible cofigure there the language which will be used in test? I think default english will be okay but for another type of tests.

Comment: The answer to pretty much every "how do I share such and such between projects" is "create a NuGet package".

Comment: In same solution :-) Do you have any idea instead of create nuget package?

Comment: Same solution doesn't really matter, you can use a NuGet package either way, and then, you can share it with other solutions as well, if you end up needing to. However, if you're insistent on not going that route, in the same solution, you can simply reference a class library (which is all your NuGet would be anyways).

Comment: OK, if I have tried to create a resx file, in new version of Visual Studio 2017 isn't designer.cs file, how can I access resx from code behind if this doesn't exist?